# checkboxInput R shiny. Insert a condition

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following code and I have created two checkbox inputs.

1. So, I created a `pos` variable that takes one of the two strings for the first input. This works.
2. Now, I want to create a new variable `pll` that fills the graph according to one of the two variables (type and employee) of my data set. I use the following code but this does not work. Do you have any idea

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shinythemes)
library(plotly)
library(ggthemes)
library(lubridate)



data <- data.frame(mitarbeiter = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF"), 
         art = c("hr", "GG", "TT", "RR", "OO", "OO"),
         creadate = as_date(c("2018-01-03", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-03")))

mitarbeiter1 <- sort(unique(data$mitarbeiter))
art1 <- sort(unique(data$art))

year_month <- function(dates) {
  paste(lubridate::year(dates),
        str_pad(lubridate::month(dates), width = 2, pad = 0),
        sep="-")
}

year_week <- function(dates) {
  paste(lubridate::year(dates),
        str_pad(lubridate::week(dates), width = 2, pad = 0),
        sep="-")
}

year_day <- function(dates) {
  paste(lubridate::year(dates),
        str_pad(lubridate::month(dates), width = 2, pad = 0),
        str_pad(lubridate::day(dates), width = 2, pad = 0),
        sep="-")
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           pickerInput("mitarbeiterName", "Name des Mitarbeiters", mitarbeiter1, 
                       options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE), multiple = TRUE),
           pickerInput("artName", "Art", art1, 
                       options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE), multiple = TRUE),
           pickerInput("period", "Zeitraum", c("day", "week", "month", "year"), 
                       options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)),
           dateRangeInput("date", "Datum auswahlen", start  = "2020-01-01"),
           checkboxInput("kumulativ", "Kumulativ"),
           checkboxInput("tf", "TF"),
           downloadButton("download", "Download")
    ),
    column(8,
           plotlyOutput("policyPlot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #create a reactive object with a NULL starting value
  listofrows <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
  
  #observe the changes in inputs and update the reactive object 
  observeEvent(c(input$mitarbeiterName, input$artName, input$date, input$period), {
    req(input$mitarbeiterName)
    req(input$artName)
    req(input$period)
    req(input$date)

    listofrows$data <- subset(data, mitarbeiter %in% input$mitarbeiterName &
                                art %in% input$artName & 
                                creadate >= input$date[1] & creadate <= input$date[2]) 
  }, ignoreInit = T, ignoreNULL = TRUE)
  
  output$policyPlot <- renderPlotly({
    req(listofrows$data)
    req(input$kumulativ)
    
    fn <- switch(
      input$period,
      day = year_day,
      week = year_week,
      month = year_month,
      year = year
    )
    
    pos <- if (input$kumulativ) "dodge" else "identity"
    pll <- if  (input$tf) type else employee

    ggplot(listofrows$data) +
      geom_bar(aes(x = fn(creadate), fill = pll), 
               stat = "count", 
               position = pos,
               show.legend = T) +
      ggtitle("Anzahl erstellte Policen (pro Mitarbeiter)") +
      xlab("Zeitraum") + ylab("Anzahl der Policen")
  })
  
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".png", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      ggsave(file, plot = output$policyPlot)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Do you have any idea how to make this work? thanks

Comment: "Does not work" means what? Is there an error message and if so, what is it?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Your code is not understandable here.

Comment: @neilfws hey I gave an example of my code. Did not write one prviously since I thought it was understandable

Answer (score 0):

Errors I noticed :

- No declaration of reactive `session_store`
- missing call to library plotly
- `aes` instead of `aes_string` when using ggplot with variable name stored in variable, because here `pll` is a string of a variable name

Please remember to provide a reproductible example when asking a question, with a minimum usable dataset.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shinythemes)
library(plotly)


data <- data.frame(employee = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                   type = c('1','2','3', '4', '2', '1'),
                   date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02"))


ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           checkboxInput("cumulative", "Cumulative"),  
           checkboxInput("tf", "TF")
    ),
    column(8,
           plotlyOutput("policyPlot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {  
  
  session_store <- reactiveValues()
  
  output$policyPlot <- renderPlotly({
    
    pos <- if (input$cumulative) "stack" else "dodge"
    pll <- if  (input$tf) 'type' else 'employee'

    # make a ggplot graph
    g <- ggplot(data) +
      geom_bar(aes_string('date', fill = pll), 
               stat = "count", 
               position = pos,
               show.legend = T)
    
    # convert the graph to plotly graph and put it in session store
    session_store$plt <- ggplotly(g)
    
    # render plotly graph
    session_store$plt
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: hey. Sorry if the example was not reproducible. The point is that I simply needed that small part of the code (the pll line) and the other code was more for context.

Comment: The point is when the code is not reproducible and the error isn't seen at first sight, people may not take the time to answer because there are too much missing elements

Comment: got it. Now, I have a reproducible example